# How to IP rotation by google AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I have a code for IP rotation by google AppScript?

I have 20 IPs in cell "B1" to "B20".

These IPs must be placed one by one (every 15 minutes) in a cell "A1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function rotate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange("B1:B20").getValues().flat();
  let idx = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("index"));
  if (isNaN(idx)) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("index", "0");
    sh.getRange("A1").setValue(vs[0]);
  } else {
    sh.getRange("A1").setValue(vs[idx]);
    if (idx < 19) {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("index", idx + 1);
    } else {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("index", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to call this with a time based trigger

Comment: Incridible . It worked thank you . so how can I stop this program at specific time in day if it is running by app script?

Comment: The trigger has time information in the event object.  With that information and some control logic  you can control it's operation.